# 'Require' bringing up a NameError

Tags: ruby, debugging, require

I've saved the following hash  under file2.rb

```
codewords = {'starmonkeys' => 'Five edged primates.'}
```

*Some of you may recognize this from the Poignant Guide!

And the following under file1.rb:

```
if __FILE__ == $0
    require File.expand_path('C:\Users\COMPAQ\My Documents\Aptana Studio Workspace\why the lucky stiff made me do this\file2.rb', __FILE__)

    print "Enter your secret sentence."
    idea = gets

    codewords.each do | real , code|
      idea.gsub!( real , code )
    end

    #Saving to a new file
    print "File encoded. Print a file name for this idea"
    idea_name = gets.strip
    File::open( "idea-"+idea_name+".txt","w" ) do |f|
      f<<idea
    end
end
```

I am bringing up a NameError: file.rb:7:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method`codewords' for main:Object (NameError)

What am I doing wrong that is bringing this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, variable declarations are scoped to the file they are defined in. That means they basically don't exist outside the scope of the file. To bridge that gap you might need to use a constant, a class, or a module, or a combination of those for namespacing purposes. For example:

```
# file2.rb

module Codewords
  CODEWORDS = { ... }
end
```

Later you can require and use this like this:

```
include Codewords

CODEWORDS.each do |real, code|
  # ...
end
```

Comment: hmm thanks...could you scroll down a little more than halfway into this page http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/book/chapter-4.html under the subtitle that says "Your Repitiveness Pays Off" and tell me why the author claims it to work there? Or am I not able to use require like that in newer Ruby versions? Thanks.

Comment: @HareKrishna: you aren't the first person to run into this problem: http://www.falsepositives.com/index.php/2005/09/12/getting-rubys-require-to-work-in-the-poignant-guide-to-ruby/

Comment: zeteic, that link really helped. Finding the fixed copy of the poignant guide is proving challenging though since a lot of the mirrors are down. Let me know if you know one. That being said, that fixed my problem and a little bit more!

Answer (score 0):

you can declare codewords to be global and then access it later by referring to it as

```
         $codewords = {'starmonkeys' => 'Five edged primates.'} #file2.rb
```

Then in file1.rb:

```
          codewords.each do | real , code|
            idea.gsub!( real , code )
          end
```